# Remove / Hide multiple divs on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I was about to drop a question, but I actually noticed my error and I solved it. So instead of deleting this post I'll post it to help some people out there.
**[The error was I wrote `getElemenstByClassName()`, instead of `getElementsByClassName()` which is funny and depressing at the same time]**

Also, show / bring back `div`s button is also there.

Here is the code:

```js
var y = document.getElementsByClassName('ex')
var i;

function removeSamples() {
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function hideSamples() {;
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].style.opacity = '0%';
  }
}

function removeSamples2() {
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function hideSamples2() {;
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].style.opacity = '100%';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
}

img,
.ex1,
.ex2,
.ex3,
.ex4,
.ex5 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

p {
  color: rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="removeSamples()">Remove Samples</button>
<button type="button" onclick="hideSamples()">Hide Samples</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removeSamples2()">Bring back Samples</button>
<button type="button" onclick="hideSamples2()">Show Samples</button>

<div class="ex">
  <img class="ex1" src="https://64.media.tumblr.com/af3438bac361d21ee1013338e4489b6f/b6f413ba8130992f-76/s1280x1920/0c9dab7eacac2a07eba7f340690514654d3e7aae.jpg">
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <img class="ex2" src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a7/8d/e7/a78de7602e65161098cf1713da457e7a.jpg">
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <img class="ex3" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ec/83/3d/ec833d04025d2ca263df3b04bbc8723c.jpg">
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <img class="ex4" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/cc/b7/e9/ccb7e9b09ec4a48478b2ff9561010000.png">
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <img class="ex5" src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5b/cd/01/5bcd015992afa05979c8b9b448fb2939.jpg">
</div>
<p>Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I'll do a brief explanation about the code above and a **brief explanation about `for` in JavaScript**.

First you make a multiple containers with the same class

```html
<div class="ex">
</div>

<div class="ex">
</div>

<div class="ex">
</div>

<div class="ex">
</div>
```

Then, put something in that container to see what is happening

```html
<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text1
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text2
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text3
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text4
  </p>
</div>
```

Now add some `CSS`

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
}

p {
  color: rgb(200,200,0);
  background-color: rgb(150,50,50);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text1
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text2
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text3
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text4
  </p>
</div>
```

Now let's insert some basic Js (`JavaScript`) code 
We will declare `x` variable to be `document.getElementsByClassName('ex')` it'll help us to write `x.style.display` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName('ex').style.display` because we will be calling it multiple times. We will leave `i` variable `undefined` for now.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('ex'); //To use it as a refrence
var i;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
}

p {
  color: rgb(200,200,0);
  background-color: rgb(150,50,50);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text1
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text2
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text3
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text4
  </p>
</div>
```

Let's make a `button` in the `HTML` then make empty `function` in `JavaScript` called `removeEx()`

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('ex'); //To use it as a refrence
var i;
function removeEx() {
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
}

p {
  color: rgb(200,200,0);
  background-color: rgb(150,50,50);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx()">
  Remove Lines
</button>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text1
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text2
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text3
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text4
  </p>
</div>
```

Now, let's focus here on `JavaScript`.
In the empty `function` we made, put empty `for` statement

```
function removeEx() {
    for()
}
```

Now let's tell the `for` statement that `i` variable is equals to `0`

```
function removeEx() {
    for(i = 0;)
}
```

Then, we will tell `for` statement to stop looping once it reaches the last class element in the `HTML` by adding `<` `smaller than` symbol so it can know where to stop. Also, we have to tell it to stop corresponding to the length of the classes which is 4 classes we have in our `HTML` by attaching `.length` method to the variable `x`.
instead of writing:

```
function removeEx() {
    for(i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('ex').length;)
}
```

We will write:

```
function removeEx() {
    for(i = 0; i < x.length;) //Remember, var x = document.getElementsByClassName('ex');
}
```

We will make the `i` variable to keep increasing by 1 until it reaches 4 (the number of our classes) then it'll stop by adding `++` operator to the `i` variable.
So we will write this

```
function removeEx() {
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
}
```

Our `for` statement is now good to go.
Let's open a curly brackets

```
function removeEx() {
    for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    }
}
```

We will evoke an event to make all `div`s with the class `ex` to get removed. So we will let `i` variable attach to `x` variable to make the spark of the event by typing `x[i]`, then we can put the event we want. For our case, the event is we want to change the `display` statement to `none`.
We will write this

```
function removeEx() {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none'; //You can put any CSS statement after x[i].style for example x[i].style.color
  }
}
```

Now let's test our code

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('ex');
var i;
function removeEx() {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
}

p {
  color: rgb(200,200,0);
  background-color: rgb(150,50,50);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx()">
  Remove Lines
</button>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text1
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text2
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text3
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text4
  </p>
</div>
```

Finally, we will add 3 more `button`s. One to get back our lines, one to make our lines semi-transparent, and one to make our lines not-transparent.
The first button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx()">Remove Lines</button>
```

The second button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx2()">Get back Lines</button>
```

The third button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx3()">50% Lines</button>
```

The forth button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx4()">Normal Lines</button>
```

The final result:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('ex'); //To use it as a refrence
var i;
function removeEx() {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function removeEx2() {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = 'block';
  }
}

function removeEx3() {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.opacity = '50%';
  }
}

function removeEx4() {
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.opacity = '100%';
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(25,25,25);
}

p {
  color: rgb(200,200,0);
  background-color: rgb(150,50,50);
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx()">Remove Lines</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx2()">Get back Lines</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx3()">50% Lines</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removeEx4()">Normal Lines</button>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text1
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text2
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text3
  </p>
</div>

<div class="ex">
  <p>
    Text4
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi opacity get value  between 0 and 1
but you used 0% and 100%!!!
Fix your code like this:

```
let y = document.querySelectorAll('.ex')
let i;

function removeSamples() {
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].style.display = 'none';
    y[i].style.opacity = 0;
  }
}


function showSamples() {
  for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].style.display = 'block';
    y[i].style.opacity = 1;
  }
}
```